# XAML button with rounded edged with perfect semicircle at the sides

Tags: xaml, button, win-universal-app, uwp, rounded-corners

I have been trying for sometime now to create a button with rounded edges whose rounded edges are actually semicircles.
My idea of implementing this is to bind the `CornerRadius` of the `Border` to the half the height of the button (I know there's no way I can do a calculation in XAML, except maybe a converter). Alas, that seems impossible because `TemplateBinding` doesn't bring up any suggestion.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius={???}>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                              FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Maybe I might have to create a new control derived from button with a `CornerRadius` dependency property. But before I go ahead, is there anyway to achieve it in XAML?
By the way, if it matters, I'm doing it for a UWP app?

Comment: Do you mean like the sides are semicircles for the "pill" type effect? Or each corner is a semicircle?

Comment: Do you want this [style](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pC9wp.png) or this [one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mMHba.png)? I personally think the second one could be a little ugly.

Comment: @ChrisW. That's the word. Pill type effect

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Certainly the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But before I go ahead, is there anyway to achieve it in XAML?

Yes, I think this is possible. But converter is needed

> I know there's no way I can do a calculation in XAML, except maybe a converter

Yes, we need to calculate in the converter and the [CornerRadius](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.cornerradius.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a `CornerRadius` type, we can't directly binding a double type of `Height/2` to it. Here I used `Button`'s height to calculate the radius.

> My idea of implementing this is to bind the CornerRadius of the Border to the half the height of the button.

I think there is no need to use a `Border` for the `ControlTemplate` of `Button`,  `Grid` and `ContentPresenter` also have the `CornerRadius` property.

For example here:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          CornerRadius="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          CornerRadius="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<local:HeightToCornerRadiusConverter x:Key="cvt" />
```

My `HeightToCornerRadiusConverter` is like this:

```cs
public class HeightToCornerRadiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var height = (double)value;
        CornerRadius radius = new CornerRadius(height / 2);
        return radius;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There is a problem here, as you can see that the `CornerRadius` is bound to the `Height` of the `Button`, so it is important that we need to set a height to `Button` when we use this style.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Never knew `ContentPresenter` had a `CornerRadius` property. Good to know.

Comment: Oh yes I did. It worked. I still will have to write a custom buttom, though, since I have to specify an explicit `height` value. I t doesn't even accept `auto`. Thanks, though. At least, I learnt something - `ContentPresenter` has a `CornerRadius` property.